# HTTP POST does not work in Android

Tags: java, android, http-post

I encountered the same problem - you need to add the user to the database with the aid of the POST. I did everything the same as in IPhone - but my android implementation for some reason does not work - users on the server are not saved.

Please tell me what is the problem? I hope for your help.

**Android HTTP POST :**

```
 public void postData() {        
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://&&&&&&&.dk/accounts/save_user/");
    try {
        facebookUserInfo = new JSONObject(mFb.request("me"));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        try {
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fbuid", facebookUserInfo.getString("id")));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("first_name", facebookUserInfo.getString("first_name")));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("last_name ", facebookUserInfo.getString("last_name")));
            System.out.println(facebookUserInfo.getString("id")+" "+facebookUserInfo.getString("first_name")+" "+facebookUserInfo.getString("last_name"));
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        System.out.println(response.getEntity()+" "+response.getStatusLine());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

**IPhone HTTP POST :**

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://&&&&&&&&&.dk/accounts/save_user/"];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //[request setPostValue:myAnnotation.google_id forKey:@"google_id"];
    [request setPostValue:fbuid forKey:@"fbuid"];
    [request setPostValue:_fbFirstName forKey:@"first_name"];
    [request setPostValue:_fbLastName forKey:@"last_name"];

    [request startSynchronous];
    NSError *error = [request error];
    if (!error) {
        NSString *response = [request responseString];
        NSLog(@"%@",response);
    }
```

Comment: "does not work" ? what is that even supposed to mean ?

Comment: have you add Internet Permission in android manifest file ?

Comment: @Chirag Raval:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> included

Comment: The problem is still relevant

Answer (score 0):

I've pulled your solution into an answer to help others in the future.

The problem is in this line.

`nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("last_name ", facebookUserInfo.getString("last_name")));`

Problems are caused by a gap(space) in the key `last_name`. so to fix this method `EntityUtils.toString(httpPost.getEntity()` returns a result row

`fbuid=100004343290749&first_name=Proba&last_name+=Proba`

after correction

`fbuid=100004343290749&first_name=Proba&last_name=Proba`